# How to print score of each fold using Gridsearchcv with multi-scorer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

i want to print score of each scoring metrics.
Such as 5 (folds) accuracy, precision, recall, f1 score.

Here is the code

```
scoring=['accuracy', 'f1_macro','precision_macro','recall_macro']

clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
scaling=StandardScaler()
param_grid = {
                  'clf__n_estimators':[50,100,200,350, 500],'clf__max_features':[ 'sqrt', 'log2'],
                  'clf__max_depth':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'clf__criterion':['gini', 'entropy']}

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('sc',scaling), ('clf', clf)])
grid_search =GridSearchCV(pipe , param_grid,  cv=GroupKFold(5),n_jobs=-1,scoring=scoring,refit='f1_macro')
grid_search.fit(X,y,groups=groups)
```

As there are 5 folds, so i am expecting 5 values against each scoring metric. How can i do that .

Edit: I can access the values like

```
grid_search.cv_results_['mean_test_recall_macro']
```

but there are 140 values inside it where as i am expecting 5, one for each  fold

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with the verbose argument? Try adding verbose = 2 to your arguments when intiializing the GridSearch. Read up on it here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html.

Comment: 5*7*2*2 = 140 different parameter combinations which yield 140 rows in the result

Comment: so if we have to get 1 for each fold, i have to get best model from grid search and then pass it to cross validated?